# createTempFile is giving The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect Error

Tags: java, runtime-error, file-permissions

I am trying to create a file using File.createTempFile(tempFileName, ".csv"). I searched and found out that this will create the file in my C drive, to which I don't have write permissions. I tried changing the default location using

```
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","D://new_location//");
```

but this is not working it seems, still giving that same error.
can someone please point out what i am doing wrong and what all things i can do?

Comment: Setting that property works for me, but then I'm not on Windows. Try `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","D:/new_location/");`

Comment: Or `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","D:\\new_location");`